# Probability of being healthy considering three risk factors

Tags: probability

There exist $3$ risk factors $A,B,C$ in order person to be sick.Probability a person to have one of them, but not the other two is $0.1$ for each factor.The probability to have two factors but not a third is $0.14$ for every two factors.The probability to have the three factors if he has A and B is $0.33$.What is the probability a person to have no factor, if he doesn't have A?

What I have tried - so we serach for $P(H|\overline{A})$ where H is the event the person is healthy(he doesn't have any factor ) and $\overline{A}$ is the person not having the risk factor $A$.

$P(H|\overline{A})=\frac{P(AH)}{P(A)}$

$P(\overline{A}) = 1 -0.9 =0.1$

so for $P(H|\overline{A})$ and $H = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{C}$

$P( \overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{C}|\overline{A})$ = $\frac{P( (\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{C}) \cap\overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}$  , but how should I continue?I am not  sure if this is the right approach and how to use then the probability given that if he has A and B then the probability of C is $0.33$ and the probability $0.14$?

Comment: The set up is not clear.  From the initial part, I assumed that you were describing $P(A\cap \overline B\cap \overline C)=.1$ (for instance) in the case of a sick patient (or, alternatively, in the case of a general patient whose health is unknown), but then later you speak of healthy patients...so are there other probabilities in that case?  If so, I'd say we don't have nearly enough information.

Comment: Just counting states...given the three properties, there are $8$ possible states a patient might be in (if you ignore Sick/Healthy as a property.  There are $16$ states if you include that.). You have direct information about $6$ of these states...you know the probabilities sum to $1$ and you have some information about a conditional probability.  That should be enough for the $8$ state problem but not the $16$ state one.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Are you familiar with [Venn diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)? You can just plot the 3 circles in this example and then fill out all the fields from the given conditions. This lets you compute easily the desired probability.